# Analysis on dataframe with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I want to be able to calculate the average 'goal','shot',and 'miss' per shooterName to use for further analysis and visualization

The code below gives me the count of the 3 attributes(shot,goal,miss) in the 'event' column sorted by 'shooterName'

Dataframe columns:

```
season  period  time    teamCode    event   goal    xCord   yCord   xCordAdjusted   yCordAdjusted   ... playerPositionThatDidEvent  timeSinceFaceoff    playerNumThatDidEvent   shooterPlayerId shooterName shooterLeftRight    shooterTimeOnIce    shooterTimeOnIceSinceFaceoff    shotDistance
```

Corresponding data

```
2020    1   16  PHI SHOT    0   -74 29  74  -29 ... C   16  11   8478439.0  Travis Konecny  R   16  16  32.649655
2020    1   34  PIT SHOT    0   49  -25 49  -25 ... C   34  9   8478542.0   Evan Rodrigues  R   34  34  47.169906
2020    1   65  PHI SHOT    0   -52 -31 52  31  ... L   65  86  8480797.0   Joel Farabee    L   31  31  48.270074
2020    1   171 PIT SHOT    0   43  39  43  39  ... C   42  9   8478542.0   Evan Rodrigues  R   42  42  60.307545   
2020    1   209 PHI MISS    0   -46 33  46  -33 ... D   38  5   8479026.0   Philippe Myers  R   38  38  54.203321
```

Current code:

```
dft['count'] = df.groupby(['shooterName', 'event'])['event'].agg(['count'])
dft
```

Current Output:

```
shooterName event count
A.J. Greer  GOAL    1
            MISS    6
            SHOT    29
Aaron Downey    GOAL    1
                MISS    4
                SHOT    35

Zenon Konopka   GOAL    8
                MISS    57
                SHOT    176
```

Desired Output:

```
shooterName event count %totalshooterNameevents
A.J. Greer  GOAL    1   .0277
            MISS    6   .1666
            SHOT    29  .805

Aaron Downey    GOAL    1 .025
                MISS    4 .1
                SHOT    35 .875

Zenon Konopka   GOAL    8 .0331
                MISS    57 .236
                SHOT    176 .7302
```

Something similar to this. My end goal is to be able to calculate each 'event' attribute as a percentage of the total 'event' by 'shooterName'. Below I added a column '%totalshooterNameevents' which is 'simply goal', 'shot', and 'miss' calculated by the sum of the 'goal, shot, and miss' per each 'shooterName'

Comment: Could you please provide the first few rows of the dataframe in order to check what it looks like?

Comment: Hopefully that is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try:

```
dft = df.groupby(['shooterName', 'event'])['event'].agg(['count']).reset_index()
dft['%total'] = dft.groupby('shooterName')['count'].apply(lambda x: x / sum(x))
print(dft)

# Output
     shooterName event  count    %total
0     A.J. Greer  GOAL      1  0.027778
1     A.J. Greer  MISS      6  0.166667
2     A.J. Greer  SHOT     29  0.805556
3   Aaron Downey  GOAL      1  0.025000
4   Aaron Downey  MISS      4  0.100000
5   Aaron Downey  SHOT     35  0.875000
6  Zenon Konopka  GOAL      8  0.033195
7  Zenon Konopka  MISS     57  0.236515
8  Zenon Konopka  SHOT    176  0.730290
```

---

Without sample, it's difficult to guess what you want. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Setup a Minimal Reproducible Example
np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame({'shooterName': np.random.choice(list('AB'), 20),
                   'event': np.random.choice(['shot', 'goal', 'miss'], 20)})

# Create an empty dataframe?
dft = pd.DataFrame(index=df['shooterName'].unique())

# Do stuff
grp = df.groupby('shooterName')
dft['count'] = grp.count()
dft = dft.join(grp['event'].value_counts().unstack('event')
                           .div(dft['count'], axis=0))
```

Output:

```
>>> dft
   count      goal   miss      shot
A     12  0.416667  0.250  0.333333
B      8  0.500000  0.375  0.125000
```

Comment: My apologies, with my limited knowledge it's difficult to explain what I want lol. I edited my original question - added the current output. I'd like to be able to add up 'goal','miss',and'shot' counts and create a 'total' attribute per 'shooterName'

Comment: Try to edit your result by hand so that I can better understand what you want.

Comment: Hopefully that gives you an idea

Comment: Thanks, I expanded a bit again. Let me know if you have any other questions. I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: @jhh19. I updated my answer. I think it's what you expect. Let me know if I'm right.

Comment: So close! I see your logic. I get an error message "KeyError: 'Requested level (event) does not match index name (None)'" when I try

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to read that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240549/discussion-between-jhh19-and-corralien).